# How can I change the position of my plot legends?

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

As the title indicates, I want to change the current position of the legends in a combined plot. The *Mathematica* code I used is

```
dataRG00 = {{2.5, 15.15}, {2.75, 13.73}, {3, 12.64}, {3.25, 
11.56}, {3.5, 10.68}, {3.75, 9.65}, {4, 9.31}, {4.25, 9.27}, {4.5,
 8.88}, {4.75, 8.21}, {5, 8.0}};
dataRG11 = {{2.5, 2.07}, {2.75, 3.0}, {3, 3.84}, {3.25, 4.58}, {3.5, 
5.56}, {3.75, 6.32}, {4, 6.73}, {4.25, 7.10}, {4.5, 7.06}, {4.75, 
7.07}, {5, 7.29}};
dataRG21 = {{2.5, 20.56}, {2.75, 19.50}, {3, 18.51}, {3.25, 
17.51}, {3.5, 16.52}, {3.75, 15.63}, {4, 14.75}, {4.25, 
13.85}, {4.5, 13.00}, {4.75, 12.26}, {5, 11.6}};
dataRG32 = {{2.5, 5.24}, {2.75, 5.14}, {3, 5.00}, {3.25, 4.51}, {3.5, 
4.25}, {3.75, 3.62}, {4, 2.56}, {4.25, 1.66}, {4.5, 1.42}, {4.75, 
1.29}, {5, 1.25}};
dataRG43 = {{2.5, 10.31}, {2.75, 10.41}, {3, 10.56}, {3.25, 
10.46}, {3.5, 10.25}, {3.75, 10.33}, {4, 10.67}, {4.25, 
10.23}, {4.5, 9.21}, {4.75, 9.60}, {5, 10.5}};
dataRG85 = {{2.5, 4.62}, {2.75, 4.64}, {3, 4.72}, {3.25, 4.67}, {3.5, 
4.46}, {3.75, 4.49}, {4, 4.37}, {4.25, 4.22}, {4.5, 4.25}, {4.75, 
4.06}, {5, 3.8}};
dataRG99 = {{2.5, 1.05}, {2.75, 0.77}, {3, 0.66}, {3.25, 0.74}, {3.5, 
0.86}, {3.75, 0.81}, {4, 0.90}, {4.25, 0.76}, {4.5, 0.90}, {4.75, 
0.90}, {5, 1.08}};
dataCH = {{2.5, 41.0}, {2.75, 42.81}, {3, 44.05}, {3.25, 45.96}, {3.5,
 47.42}, {3.75, 49.18}, {4, 50.68}, {4.25, 52.90}, {4.5, 
55.27}, {4.75, 56.60}, {5, 56.48}};

col = {Darker[Green], Red, Blue, Yellow, Orange, Cyan, Magenta, 
Darker[Gray]};
ley = {"Box", "1:1 linear", "2:1 boxlet", "3:2 boxlet", "4:3 boxlet", 
"8:5 boxlet", "Other resonances", "Chaotic"};
plrange = {{2.4, 5.1}, {-2, 60}};

legendPlot[xl_List] := 
ListPlot[xl, Frame -> True, 
PlotStyle -> Table[{Thickness[0.003], col[[i]]}, {i, 1, 8}], 
Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 15}, 
FrameLabel -> {"α", "Percentage %"}, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
PlotRange -> plrange, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 600, 
Epilog -> 
 Inset[Grid[
 MapIndexed[{Graphics[{col[[First[#2]]], 
      Inset[Style[{\[FilledCircle], \[FilledSquare], \
 \[FilledDiamond], \[FilledUpTriangle], \[FilledDownTriangle], \
 \[EmptyCircle], \[EmptySquare], \[EmptyDiamond]}[[First[#2]]], 15]], 
      Thickness[0.08], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, 
     AspectRatio -> 0.5, ImageSize -> 20], 
    Style[ley[[First[#2]]], Bold, FontSize -> 10, 
     FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]} &, xl]], 
Offset[{-2, -2}, Scaled[{1, 1}]], {Right, Top}]]

P0 = legendPlot[{dataRG00, dataRG11, dataRG21, dataRG32, dataRG43, 
dataRG85, dataRG99, dataCH}]
```

which produces the following plot

[image]

Obviously, the position of the legends is wrong since they overlap part of the plot. What I want, is to move the legends outside the frame of the plot and particularly at the right hand side of it and adjust it at the middle of the y range. I "played" a lot with `Offset` and `Scaled` but I without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried [`PlotLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/PlotLegends/ref/PlotLegend.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
With[{xl = {dataRG00, dataRG11, dataRG21, dataRG32, dataRG43, dataRG85, dataRG99, dataCH}}, 
Row[{ListPlot[xl, Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> Table[{Thickness[0.003], col[[i]]}, {i, 1, 8}], 
  Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 15}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"\[Alpha]", "Percentage %"}, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
PlotRange -> plrange, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 600], 
Grid[MapIndexed[{Graphics[{col[[First[#2]]], 
     Inset[Style[{\[FilledCircle], \[FilledSquare], \
\[FilledDiamond], \[FilledUpTriangle], \[FilledDownTriangle], \
\[EmptyCircle], \[EmptySquare], \[EmptyDiamond]}[[First[#2]]], 15]], 
     Thickness[0.08], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, AspectRatio -> 0.5,
     ImageSize -> 20], 
   Style[ley[[First[#2]]], Bold, FontSize -> 10, 
    FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]} &, xl]]}, Spacer[10]]]
```

[image]

If you have Version 9, you can also use `PlotLegends` and `LineLegend`:

```
 ListPlot[{dataRG00, dataRG11, dataRG21, dataRG32, dataRG43, dataRG85, 
 dataRG99, dataCH}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> Table[{Thickness[0.003], col[[i]]}, {i, 1, 8}], 
 Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 15}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\[Alpha]", "Percentage %"}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
 PlotRange -> plrange, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 600, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[ley, LegendMarkers -> Automatic]]
```

[image]

**Update:** "to place the legends at the upper right part of the plot" and "to increase the vertical distance between each label", you can use

```
 PlotLegends ->  Placed[LineLegend[ley, LegendMarkers -> Automatic, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> {{30, 25}}], {After, Top}]
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Thank you! One more question... what if I want to move the legends at the upper right part of the plot (always outside)? Or increase the vertical distance between each label (i.e. 1:1, 2:1) ?

Comment: I do have the 9.0 version.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, to increase the vertical distance between lables you can use the option `LegendMarkerSize`; e.g., `LegendMarkerSize -> {{55, 25}}` where the second element of the list controls the vertical size of each legend. Re placement of the legend on the upper right,  I think there was a Q/A about that; I will post the link if I can find it.

Comment: Many many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Took me a while to figure it out myself. The co-ordinates are:

```
{
  {Position on graphic in x, Position on graphic in y}, 
  {Part of plot legend that should be at the assigned position on graphic}
}
```

So: `{{0.9, 0.9}, {1, 1}}` assigns a location on my graphic 90% up the graphic and 90% to the right, and puts the upper right corner of my plot legend at this point.

or `{{0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5}}` puts the middle of my plot legend in the middle of my graphic.

Answer (score 4):

```
PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[LineLegend[Automatic, {"Short circuit"}], {0.15, 0.7}]
```

`0.15` and `0.7` are the inputs for placing the legend in the plot. `0.15` means the centre of a legend is at 15% of x-axis length and `0.7` means 70% length of the y-axis. In fact, if you input `0.5,0.5`, you will be placing the legend in the centre of graph or 1,0 means at the end of the x-axis where y=0. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[ LineLegend[{"xx", "yy", "zz", "kk", "ww"}, 
                        Joined -> Automatic, LegendFunction -> Frame, 
                        LegendMarkerSize -> {{35, 10}}], 
           {{0.2, 0.5}, {0.2, 0.02}}]
```

The position is given by `Placed[***,  {{0.2, 0.5}, {0.2, 0.02}}]`

Comment: what do the coordinates above {{0.2, 0.5}, {0.2, 0.02}} mean? The documentation on Placed does not explain how those coordinates are defined. thank you.